# I am not able to display image from my local storage in android

Tags: android, image, android-studio, local-storage, fileinputstream

I have 20k image files in a folder inside my local storage, I need to display the image by its file name from local storage. How to do it? I attached my code here:

```
 if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
            .equals(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)) {
        String filePath = File.separator + "sdcard" + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + "convertMp3ToDb" + File.separator + "ldoce6pics" + File.separator + fileName;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            String entry = null;
            while ((entry = fis.toString()) != null) {
                if (!entry.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    File Mytemp = File.createTempFile("TCL", "jpg", getContext().getCacheDir());
                    Mytemp.deleteOnExit();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Mytemp);
                    for (int c = fis.read(); c != -1; c = fis.read()) {
                        try {
                            fos.write(c);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    FileInputStream MyFile = new FileInputStream(Mytemp);
                    final Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(MyFile);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bit);

                }
            }
            fis.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Comment: show ur logcat log

Comment: try to 1. Use image libraries like Glide(there are others as well i prefer glide) - for that convert file path from string to uri 2. You can also use loaders for the same to setup in bitmap

Comment: Do some log and post it

Comment: No logcat,  error but their is no action being performed, image is not displaying

Comment: You're using try catch. Remove it and check the log again. There might be an error happening in that block.

Comment: @MahalakshmiSaravanan check below answer

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
            .equals(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)) {
        String filePath = File.separator + "sdcard" + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + "convertMp3ToDb" + File.separator + "ldoce6pics" + File.separator + fileName;
        File f = new File(filePath);
         if(f.exits()){

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

         }else{
             // invalid path
           }
     }
  }
```

Update Section:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                .equals(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)) {
  // this never be true see below image 
 }
```

[image]

You have to do like this

```
 File file  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/Android/obb/convertMp3ToDb/ldoce6pics/"+fileName);

        if (file.exists()) {
            // your condition should ne likr this.
        }
```

Comment: if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
            .equals(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)) this condition is false may I know what would be the issue then

Comment: in my opinion you are doing it wrong way?  
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() .equals(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) will never be true.

Comment: Then how to access the internal storage images

Comment: @MahalakshmiSaravanan open your file in file explore and go to its properties and then write it path what you see in your phone.